# Update a column based on the records of another columns in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

I have a table TRANSACTIONS in `sqlite` and I added a new column to it. What I want is to fill the new column based on the records of the same rows. For example 
 (the below table doesn't contain the actual data...):

```
productId         brc                newColumn
   10032         10032-100101          32-A
   10231         10231-100102          231-B
```

I have succeeded in getting the desired output of the newColumn:

```
//The below statement gives me the newColumn result
select cast(substr(productId, 2, 5) as integer) || 
case 
    when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 0 then ''
    when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 1 then '-Α'
    when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 2 then '-Β'
    when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 3 then '-Γ'
    when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 4 then '-Δ'
when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 5 then '-Ε'     
END as newColumn
from TRANSACTIONS
```

Now, I want to update the table! I tried :

```
update TRANSACTIONS
set newColumn = (    
   select cast(substr(productId, 2, 5) as integer) || 
   case 
       when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 0 then ''
       when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 1 then '-Α'
       when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 2 then '-Β'
       when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 3 then '-Γ'
       when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 4 then '-Δ'
   when cast(substr(brc, 37, 1) as integer) == 5 then '-Ε'      
   END from TRANSACTIONS
   )

where brc = brc;
```

But I get the same value in all the rows of the newColumn... What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the inner `select`, Since you want to build `newColumn` from the data in a given row.

In other databases, I have seen such a query give an error about "multiple rows returned" (by the inner select). Not so in sqlite. It probably updates all the rows with the value from the first row.

Another way to fix it would be to alias the TRANSACTIONS table in both places, and add a `where t1.brc = t2.brc` in the inner select. But that's making the database do more work than it has to.

Comment: I removed the inner `select` and it worked! 
Yes, exactly that was happening in my case and I wasn't getting any warning...